# PHP XML losing attributes

Tags: php, xml

i have a problem while I load xml string into SimpleXMLElement ( i tried also with DOCDocument but result is the same). In XML i have this :

```
<definedNames>
        <definedName name="name1" Id="1" hidden="1">NAME_TEST</definedName>
        <definedName name="name2" Id="4" hidden="1">NAME_TEST_2</definedName>
</definedNames>
```

Now i need access to specific   tag using 'name' attribute. But always when i tried to print_r, var_dump or smth else i always see all other attributes, but when comes to  i see only array with

```
[0] = > NAME_TEST, 
[1] =>  NAME_TEST_2
```

I tried also xpath, but everytime when i refer to attributes inside  i get empty array.

So for now i tried : xpath, SimpleXMLDom, DOCDocument but result is always the same - empty array. Any clue ?

@edit

```
$xl->LoadTemplate('#xl/workbook.xml'); 
            if (isset($workbook) && is_array($workbook) && count($workbook > 0)) {
                $dom = new DOMDocument();
                $dom->loadXML($xl->Source);
                $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
                foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//definedName') as $definedName) {
                    echo $definedName->getAttribute('name');
                }
            } else {
                $TBS->Source = preg_replace('~\<definedNames\>.*\<\/definedNames\>~', '', $TBS->Source);
            }
```

@edit2 - xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x15" xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main">
 <definedNames>
        <definedName name="name1" Id="1" hidden="1">NAME_TEST</definedName>
        <definedName name="name2" Id="4" hidden="1">NAME_TEST_2</definedName>
</definedNames>
</workbook>
```

i know there is smth like , but i already tried :

```
$xpath->evaluate('//workbook/definedNames/definedName[@*]')
```

or

```
$xpath->evaluate('/workbook/definedNames/definedName[@name="name1"]')
```

still result is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With DOMDocument, you use Xpath to fetch values or nodes.

Load the XML into a document and create an DOMXpath instance for it:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

Fetch a node value as string:

```
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//definedName[@name="name1"])'));
```

Output:

```
string(9) "NAME_TEST"
```

Fetch all definedName element data into an array:

```
$byName = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//definedName') as $definedName) {
  $byName[] = [
    'name' => $definedName->getAttribute('name'),
    'id' => $definedName->getAttribute('Id'),
    'hidden' => $definedName->getAttribute('hidden'),
    'text' => $definedName->nodeValue
  ];
}
var_dump($byName);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "name1"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["hidden"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["text"]=>
    string(9) "NAME_TEST"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "name2"
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["hidden"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["text"]=>
    string(11) "NAME_TEST_2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i still got this problem, beacuse $xpath->evaluate('//definedName') is empty.. Before i tried to work with that xml, i even saved it in txt file, and i can see that xml string as i show you i 1 post. But still i cant access to definedName via attributes.

Comment: It is not, see https://eval.in/174419 - Did you post the whole XML? It might contain namespaces.

Comment: Ok, thing with namespace give me some hint:                           $xml = str_replace('xmlns=', 'ns=', $xml);

Comment: You should not remove the namespaces, register a prefix for them on the DOMXpath and use it.

Answer (score 0):

try `simplexml_load_string()`

```
$p = '<definedNames>
        <definedName name="name1" Id="1" hidden="1">NAME_TEST</definedName>
        <definedName name="name2" Id="4" hidden="1">NAME_TEST_2</definedName>
</definedNames>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($p);
echo $xml->definedName[0]->attributes()->name;
echo $xml->definedName[1]->attributes()->name;
```

or use foreach to get all attaributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `attributes()` method on each element of the SimpleXMLElement Object. You can then access them:

```
$xml = '<definedNames>
        <definedName name="name1" Id="1" hidden="1">NAME_TEST</definedName>
        <definedName name="name2" Id="4" hidden="1">NAME_TEST_2</definedName>
</definedNames>';

$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($x as $element) {
    var_dump($element->attributes());
}
```

The above returns:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "name1"
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["hidden"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "name2"
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["hidden"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

You can then access individual attributes by using in the loop:

```
foreach ($x as $element) {
    $element->attributes()->hidden;
    $element->attributes()->Id;
    $element->attributes()->name;
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks u for reply but i tried smth like you guys provides, and results are the same.
I got 0 matches, when i dump `$x` i see only NAME_TEST etc without attributes that i need.

Comment: I don't know what you're after then. When you `var_dump` just the `SimpleXmlElement` it won't show the attributes, you have to use `attributes()` to access them, either in a loop, or one by one `$x[0]->attributes()->hidden;` or `foreach ($x as $element->attributes()) {echo $x->Id;}`